# React-DOM is not rendering the elements in the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, react-dom

In the head section I have added the CDN links which are need to be done.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>First Component</title>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom-factories@1.0.0/index.js"></script>
</head>
```

In the body section I have mentioned  element in which I have written the react code please check
the  element in the body is working fine but the react component is not rendering.

```
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      class Pet extends React.component{
        render (){
            const h2 = ReactDOMFactories.h2(null, "Potter");
            const img = ReactDomFactories.img({src:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Indian_spitz_adult.JPG/640px-Indian_spitz_adult.JPG",
            alt:"Potter my dog"});
            return ReactDomFactories.div(null, h2,img);
        }
      }
     ReactDom.render(React.createElement(Pet),document.getElementById("app"));
    </script> 
</body>
```

In the above code  element is showing fine but react-dom is not rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have couple of typos in your code:

- `React.component` should be `React.Component`
- `ReactDomFactories` is `ReactDOMFactories` (you got it right in `h2` :))
- `ReactDom.render` is actually `ReactDOM.render`

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>First Component</title>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom-factories@1.0.0/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    class Pet extends React.Component{
      render (){
          const h2 = ReactDOMFactories.h2(null, "Potter");
          const img = ReactDOMFactories.img({src:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6e/Indian_spitz_adult.JPG/640px-Indian_spitz_adult.JPG",
          alt:"Potter my dog"});
          return ReactDOMFactories.div(null, h2,img);
      }
    }
   ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Pet),document.getElementById("app"));
  </script> 
</body>
```